# Nesting in Less - for tags

Tags: html, less

I want to nest tags in the less something like this:

```
.removeOutline{
    outline : none;
    .form-group{
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
        margin-top: 7px;
        max-width:@full-width;
        width:auto;
    }
}
```

When I have HTML like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 removeOutline" tabindex="3">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback has-clear searchManual">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to specify form-group with div.

Comment: *I want to specify form-group with div.* - Can you please clarify this further (maybe specify the output selector that you are looking for). If all that you are looking for is a selector like `.removeOutline div.form-group` then just make `div.form-group` as the nested selector in Less.

Comment: Is this right then?:.removeOutline{
 outline : none;
 .form-group{
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  max-width:@full-width;
  width:auto;
  div.form-control-clear{
   z-index:999;
   position: absolute;}}

Comment: Well, apart from a missing closing brace there is nothing wrong with that Less code and it will compile properly. However *right or not* depends on your HTML structure. I don't see the `div.form-control-clear` in your markup provided in question.